# Node.js request.open("GET", "what.should.I.put.here.html/getAll", true);

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

So I've designed a majority of my website, and now I'm hosting it on a school based host service. I have two folders: a client folder that contains (basically) my html pages and my main.js page, and a server folder that contains the api that my main.js is calling to. When building, I would form my request as `request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/getAll", true);`. However, now that I am hosting it on a school hosting server, I'm not sure where I should call.

I've attempted using: 
`http://personal.psu.edu/dbp5208/PersonalWebsite/getAll`
`http://personal.psu.edu/dbp5208/PersonalWebsite/Server/server.js/getAll` 
`http://personal.psu.edu/dbp5208/PersonalWebsite/Server/getAll` 
`./getAll` 
`request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/getAll", true);` works on the school server, but only on my machine.

main.js file location: `personalwebsite/client/js/main.js`
server.js file location: `personalwebsite/server/server.js`

Comment: The domain of the server instead of localhost. If your API and static pages/JS are hosted on the same domain, you can even omit it entirely and just use the path after the hostname, i.e. `/getAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose when working locally, you have to start the (Node.js-based?) server first, by something like `npm run start` or similar. When the server starts, it listens on port 3000 of localhost. That's what you're accessing.

The problem is - I think - that just uploading the server files does not start your server on the schools web server. The school server also has to run your server code, which then listens on a separate port. If your hosting service doesn't support running Node.js programs, it won't work.

The client works because the hosting service's webserver just delivers the files statically (a very basic task), but the JavaScript then runs on your browser.